# Attaching equalizer and bass boost

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to attach an equalizer and bass boost to the currently playing audio doing something like this:

```
eq = Equalizer(0, MediaPlayer().audioSessionId)
bb = BassBoost(0, MediaPlayer().audioSessionId)
```

However, when I play some audio and check to see if the media player is running, `MediaPlayer().isPlaying` returns false.

In the olden days apparently you could pass an audio session ID of 0 to provide a global equalizer or bass boost. Unfortunately, [this is deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer), and an ID of 0 now indicates something went wrong. I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29531184/5472966) from 2015, so this has been deprecated for a long time.

How can I figure out the right `audioSessionId` for the currently playing audio? I've looked at the [AudioEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect) and [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/MediaPlayer) documentation but still don't understand how this should be done.

I primarily use Google Music to play my music so if I have to hard code its ID to make this work that is an acceptable solution for me. This is just for an app I'm working on for fun as a learning experience (I'm new to Android and Kotlin).

Full code base [here](https://github.com/McGlothlin/Android-Equalizer).

Comment: Making a new MediaPlayer and asking if it is playing or for it's audioSessionId is not going to help.

Comment: @McGlothlin Did you manage to figure out a way to find active audio session ID?

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov no I haven't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply effects to audioSessionId 0 and it might work on many devices, but it is deprecated as you noted. It's unlikely Google Play Music has a stable audio Session id.

Applying effects to anything but your own app or an app that has provisions for letting its audio session id be known is no longer supported - see issue marked as Won't Fix:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36936557

Comment: This is certainly true; I've tested with an equalizer someone else wrote (using 0 as the audioSessionId) and it works on both my emulator and physical device. I was just hoping there was a non-deprecated way...